# Deploying an Application Page with code behind to a document library using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: deployment, visual-studio, application-pages

I'm developing a new Application Page using Visual Studio 2010 with code behind it. When I deploy the solution, the page gets deployed to the _layouts folder but I would like to have the page for users to view as if it was a normal page in the Pages-document library.

Is this possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application pages are shared across all sites on the server, whereas a site page is specific to one site.

By default, most of the pages that appear when you create a SharePoint site are site pages. A site page can be added **to a SharePoint page library**. Users can customize a site page by using tools such as SharePoint Designer. A site page can also host features such as dynamic Web Parts, and Web Part Zones.

**Application pages cannot do these things**. However an application page is the best type of page to create if you want the page to contain custom code. Although you can add custom code to a site page, the code stops running when the user customizes the page by using tools such as SharePoint Designer. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx))

You can create a Web Part Page and [deploy it to the library](http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=56)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want to add custom code so I'm definitely going with creating an application page. Now the problem is that the page resides in the _layouts folder and I would like to have it in a document library with other pages. Is this possible at all? Cheers!

Comment: You could move the custom code to some controls, create a new page that is inherited from WebPartPage, add these controls to this page and deploy this page to the Library. As you can read in post that I provided, the Application page cannot be deployed to the Library.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, you got me on the right track! What I did was that I moved all of my code (except for SharePoint 2010 content placeholders like AdditionalPageHead etc) from the Application Page to a new Visual Web Part that I created in Visual Studio 2010. After deploying the new web part, I created a new blank page in the Pages-library and I just Inserted the new custom web part to the page and voila! Works perfectly and now the application runs inside a page that resides in a document library - exactly what I wanted! Thanks Alexander!!